Can New Member States Be Admitted to the EU with an Ongoing Territorial Conflict?
Cyprus joined the European Union in 2004 despite its unresolved territorial division [Robert Schuman Foundation] between the Republic of Cyprus and the Turkish Republic of Northern Cyprus, which is only recognized by Turkey. Given that the EU typically emphasizes stability and peaceful resolution of disputes as part of its accession criteria, how did Cyprus navigate these challenges to become a member?
There are also other regions with territorial disputes have sought EU membership:
Western Balkans: Countries like Serbia and Kosovo have unresolved territorial issues. The EU has made it clear that such disputes must be resolved before accession. For instance, Serbia's progress toward EU membership is contingent upon normalizing relations with Kosovo. [European Council on Foreign Relations]
Ukraine and Moldova: Both countries have territorial conflicts—Ukraine with Crimea and parts of Donbas, and Moldova with Transnistria. Their EU membership aspirations are complicated by these disputes, and the EU has emphasized the need for peaceful resolutions. [Carnegie Endowment for International Peace]

TBH, it's less than clear to me from your last link that the EU has put such an emphasis.

I think you are confusing between EU and NATO. While both obviously do prefer a country have settled borders before it joins, NATO as a military alliance is more particular about it than EU (which is an economic alliance) which is more flexible about it.

I am not confusing EU and NATO- simply don't know where the EU stands on this


Can New Member States Be Admitted to the EU with an Ongoing Territorial Conflict?

I think yes if by "Ongoing Territorial Conflict" you mean "territorial disputes" (as you seem to) rather than open warfare. Spain was admitted (in 1985) to the EU while having a territorial dispute with the UK over Gibraltar (still ongoing). The UK was in the EU then (since 1973).
Greece (EU member since 1981) had & has territorial disputes with Turkey, which is not an EU member, but also started accession talks (now frozen). I'm not entirely sure when those disputes started, but they've been going on at least since the 1970s.
As for your own example, Cyprus, since it is a more recent accession, we have more of the documents online. I'm not entirely sure what is the most relevant bit, but probably from the Cyprus accession protocol:

Article 1

The application of the acquis shall be suspended in those areas of the Republic of Cyprus in which the Government of the Republic of Cyprus does not exercise effective control.

The Council, acting unanimously on the basis of a proposal from the Commission, shall decide on the withdrawal of the suspension referred to in paragraph 1.


[...]
Article 4
In the event of a settlement, the Council, acting unanimously on the basis of a proposal from the Commission, shall decide on the adaptations to the terms concerning the accession of Cyprus to the European Union with regard to the Turkish Cypriot Community.

There was actually a pretty formal settlement attempt as the Annan Plan. This actually failed with the Greek Cypriot side rejecting the proposal in a referendum in 2004, but nonetheless, EU accession was not affected, completing in the same year. And FWTW, much more recently Erdogan too has been rejecting other similar attempts at federalization of Cyprus, asking for a straight two-states solution but "adding that the Turkish north is the “apple of Turkey’s eye.”" That (July 2024) piece also mentions that

Multiple attempts to find a compromise settlement over the years have failed, the last one in 2017 in Crans-Montana, Switzerland; and formal talks have not resumed since then.

As you seem to intuit by referring to Cyprus foremost, their situation of not having full territorial control is indeed perhaps the most relevant to e.g. Moldova or Georgia, and perhaps even Ukraine.
The only thing that I think hasn't been done in terms of precedent is admitting into the EU a country still fighting an active war, rather than this kind of "frozen conflict".

Territorial Disputes are not an Admission Criterion
I think you might be mistaking NATO membership with EU membership.  To join NATO, you must be in peacetime, but admissibility into the EU are based on the Copenhagen criteria:

You must have a Democratic Government
Your nation's legal system must enforce Rule of Law
Your citizens must be guaranteed human rights as defined by the European Convention on Human Rights.
Your nation must respect and protect its minorities.
Your nation must have a stable market economy.
You must bring your laws into alignment with Acquis Communautaire (AKA: EU law).

It is possible for the Union to deny membership for other reasons, but these are the only criteria that will automatically deny membership.  Technically speaking, a country can be in the middle of an all out war and still join the EU as long as the European Parliament agrees to it.

Theoretical answer
Given unanimous agreement of all EU members, pretty much anything is possible - they could even decide to admit Syria or Somalia into the Union if they really wanted to. Remember that laws, rules, and traditions are merely pieces of paper, not laws of physics. Anything and everything can be turned upside down and sideways if enough politicians wish to make it happen.
Realpolitik answer
There's no reason for European voters to support such an endeavor. Accepting refugees from Ukraine pretty much pays for itself thanks to their low crime rates and high labor participation rate. Helping Ukraine is somewhat costly but far cheaper than what it would cost to fully integrate them as an EU member, not to mention the risks of a potential direct war with Russia.
So Ukraine will be invited to many summits, sign dozens of "declarations", participate in various "roadmaps", enter into "partnerships", but in reality, it's extremely unlikely to actually join the EU within the next decade. It would be too costly, too risky, and will have too few upsides.
It doesn't matter for Ukrainian citizens who are willing to move
If we forget about Ukraine as a "country" and focus on Ukrainian citizens, entering the EU isn't all that important. Millions of people have been able to settle in the EU thanks to the war, and millions more will join them once the war is over and men are officially allowed to leave the country. Why wait for "EU membership" when you can hop on a train and start in the EU in less than 24 hours?
It's extremely counterintuitive, but while the war has brought tremendous suffering, those Ukrainians who have been able to move to the EU have gained access to new opportunities that are an order of magnitude better than before. Their living standards have often improved, and their children will likely have significantly better educational and career prospects than they would have had in pre-war Ukraine.

"It’s extremely counterintuitive but the war has likely been a net benefit to Ukrainians who have been able to freely move to the EU and other developed countries thanks to the war." Uh... this doesn't seem like something Ukrainians would agree with. "Their life standards have gone up overnight" except for losing their homes, possessions, and communities. This is an astonishingly bad take.

@kaya3 that's why it's highly counterintuitive. Yes they've lost their homes but... if you lived in a mid-size Ukrainian town the value of that real estate was low and the quality of living was lower still. Moving to Poland (let alone Germany or Norway) is such a drastic increase in (potential) income and quality of living, that it wipes away all losses from the war. It won't help those who've lose a loved on, but only ~0.25% of Ukrainian citizens have died in the war so far. Assuming each had 10 close relatives, only 2.5% of Ukrainians have lost a close relative.

@kaya3 people don't like talking about this because politicians and newspapers want to frame everything in terms of state rather than humans. But it's the humans who matter not the "state" and humans had a pretty unenviable life quality even before the invasion of Crimea, especially outside of Kiev. I've been there pre-war, I have relatives there, I know what I'm talking about. Moving to the West is a huge win for them.

@JonathanReez: For that matter, assume each had 30 close relatives and the numbers still make it a small minority (especially since the overlap in family trees of the deceased will be quite high).  Still, you might want to rephrase as "net benefit to most Ukranians" so you aren't balancing an economic benefit to the majority vs loss of family of the minority and trying to assign economic value to those deaths.

@JonathanReez I appreciate that you want to make a counterintuitive statement, but besides being contrary to intuition, your statement is also completely contrary to reality. For your statement to be believable, you have to believe that an ordinary Ukrainian existence in an ordinary town is worse than losing everything you own and everyone you know in order to temporarily live in the spare room of a stranger's house, in a country where you barely speak the language and have no citizenship rights. Your children, who only speak Ukrainian, will have no friends and cannot go to school.

You can say "I've been to Ukraine and know what it's like", but this doesn't lend any believability to your statement. Have you spoken to any Ukrainian refugees and asked them if the change is actually a net positive for them? Have any told you that it is? It is certainly not difficult to find Ukrainian refugees who say that actually, being forced to flee their country and communities has been a bad thing for them.

@kaya3 I’m a Ukrainian citizen by descent and yes, I’ve spoken to many refugees.
